# get timestamp with timezone from db in milliseconds postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a timestamp in my database of type "timestamp with time zone" and I need to get this value in ms.

Query:

```
'SELECT timestamp from default_dataset where type=$1 and device_id=$2 order by timestamp desc limit 1'
```

Result --> `2017-07-20T10:55:20.000Z`

I need my result in milliseconds. How to do this? I try truncate but cant get anything...

Answer (score 0):

Search for Epoch in Time/Date Functions of postgres documentation.

Comment: I have a timestamp in ms like "1500556164805" and my database retrieve "1500555684".

I need the db returns a value in ms to compare with another timestamp in ms.

with SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp) from default_dataset where type='probing_live' and device_id='f051b333-8f1f-4e65-9acc-e76470a87f47' order by timestamp desc limit 1

Comment: Is float if necessary, multiply by 1000.